# How to use Process Monitor to determine which DLL is causing a BadImageFormatException

Tags: asp.net, windows, 64-bit, process-monitor

I have a large web application, which is supposed to run in a 64 bit process.  However, when I set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to False on my App Pool, I get the following error trying to run the app in IE:

*is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)*

The application name at he beginning of the error message is missing, i.e. I have not lost it during copy and paste.

I have been advised to use Process Monitor to determine which application/DLL load is actually causing the error, but I have no idea where to start with this.  Could somebody please advise?

**EDIT:**  I have tried filtering Process Monitor on only w3wp.exe and only file system and process events, but simply attempting a navigate to the root URL yields 34,012 events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a console application that is built to be x64 only and use it to dynamically load all the referenced dll's one by one with console output between loads.  When the console application fails to load one of the dll's, you'll know which one it is.

Comment: That's a good strategy, but this solution is a really, really complex tangle of dependencies.  It comprises 320 projects, maybe 20 of which are web projects that reference the rest, and are referenced by 1 core web project.  It would take a year of Sundays to apply your strategy here.

Comment: @ProfK, doesn't matter how many dll's there are, just use `Directory.GetFiles` to recursively look for all dll's in your project hierarchy and load them one by one.  You don't need your console to actually reference them, load them with reflection.

Comment: I think I will actually do that, when I can reproduce this scenario again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a ASP.Net application. Have you set your main web project(s) **Platform Target** to x86.

You can find the setting in **Project Properties | Build | Platform target**

Also do any of your projects reference any 3rd Party Libraries? If so do you know whether they are 32-bit or 64-bit dlls?

Comment: It is an ASP.NET app (hence the tag), but the main project is set to 'Any CPU'.  This app is supposed to build as a 64-bit app, but I'm currently scanning the very long list of referenced libs to check if 1 might be set to x86.